# What is the distribution of the product of a Bernoulli (0,1) & a normal random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and Z a Bernoulli random variable with
$\begin{equation}\qquad \Pr(Z=z) = \begin{cases}
p & \mbox{if $z = 1$}, \\ 
1-p & \mbox{if $z = 0$},\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases} \end{equation}$

I'm struggling to work out the distribution of $y=Z\cdot X$. It seems straightforward if $Z$ takes values 1 and -1 ([The product of a normal and Bernoulli variables, independent from each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064541/the-product-of-a-normal-and-bernoulli-variables-independent-from-each-other)). But if I try the same approach, I get stuck at some stage with

$\Pr(Y\leq y) = \frac{1}{2} \Pr(1\cdot X \leq y) +  \frac{1}{2} \Pr(0\cdot X \leq y)$.

Not sure how to go on from here. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y \in (-\infty,0)$. Then:

$F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb P(ZX \le y) = \mathbb P(ZX \le y | Z = 1)\mathbb P(Z=1) + \mathbb P(ZX \le y | Z=0)\mathbb P(Z=0) =$

$ p\mathbb P(X \le y) + (1-p)\mathbb P(0 \le y) = p\mathbb P(X \le y) = p\int_{-\infty}^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx $

Similar for $y \in [0,+\infty)$, we get:

$F_Y(y) =p\mathbb P(X \le y) + (1-p)\mathbb P(0 \le y) = 1-p + p\mathbb P(X \le y) = 1-p +p\int_{-\infty}^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx $

So, when $\mu$ is the distribution of $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $\mu_{Y}$ is given by:

$\mu_Y(A) = (1-p)\cdot \delta_{0}(A) + p\cdot \mu(A)$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dominik Kutek what is $\delta_{0}$ in here?

Comment: $\delta_0$ is common notation for Dirac delta distribution at $0$, that is - probability measure such that $\delta_0(\{0\})=1$ (i.e all mass is accumulated in a single point). In other words, $\delta_0(A) = 1$ if $0 \in A$ and $\delta_0(A) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Dominik Kutek So, if I want to find the value of $z$ for which the pdf of $y$ is maximum, then $z$ should be $0$ since there is additive (1-p) term. Is that right?