# The distribution of the product of Gaussian variable and Rademacher variable.

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have two independent variables: $X$ follows from standard Gaussian distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$; $Y$ follows from Rademacher distribution, i.e., $Y$ can be either $-1$ or $1$ with the same probability.

My question is:

For a new random variable of $Z=XY$, What is the probability density function?   Or can we have some concentration inequalities for $Z$ (e.g., show how $Z$ approaches its expectation, etc.)?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064541/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325786/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Y$ takes values in $\{-1,1\}$ while the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about $0$, then 
$XY$ has the same distribution as $X$.  Hint: condition on $Y$.

Comment: Many thanks. But could you please show the whole procedure? @Robert Israel

Comment: I think his hint is almost the whole argument.  You understand that if $X$ has a symmetric distribution then $-X$ has the same distribution (as shown below by Henry), right?  Well, conditional on $Y$, $XY$ is either $X$ or $-X$, and $P(XY \leq t) = \text{E}[P(XY \leq t \mid Y)]$.

Answer (score 6):

Since $X$ has a symmetic distribution about $0$, you have $P(X-0 \le x) = P(0-X \le x)$, i.e. $P(X \le x) = P(-X \le x)$.

Now consider the cumulative distribution function $P(Z \le x)$.

This is $P(XY \le x)=P(XY \le x|Y=1)P(Y=1)+P(XY \le x|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)$ which is $P(X \le x|Y=1)P(Y=1)+P(-X \le x|Y=-1)P(Y=-1)$  which by the symmetry and independence is $P(X\le x)(P(Y=1)+P(Y=-1))=P(X\le x)$ the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

So $Z$ has the same distribution as $X$.

This uses the symmetry of the distribution of $X$ about $0$, $X$ and $Y$ being independent, and $Y$ taking the values $-1$ and $1$.  It does not use the normal distribution, or $Y$ taking its values with equal probability.