# Transformation of a random variable $Z = XY$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $X$ follows a standard normal distribution and that the support of Y is $S_{Y} = (-1,1)$ with $P(Y = -1) = P(Y = 1)$. Let $Z=XY$. By using the CDF method and MGF method, derive the probability density function of Z.

The problem I have with this question is that I do not know how to use the information I am given about $Y$.

My attempt:

MGF METHOD: $$E(e^{tZ})=E(e^{tX}e^{tY})=\frac{e^{t^2}}{2}E(e^{tY})$$

CDF METHOD:
$$P(Z\leq a)=P(XY \leq a)=P(X \leq \frac{a}{Y})$$

I notice $Y$ is an even function. I'm not sure what other useful information it gives me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348263/the-distribution-of-the-product-of-gaussian-variable-and-rademacher-variable

Comment: Moreover, $e^{tXY}\neq e^{tX}e^{tY}$.