# Distribution of the product of a standard normal and uniform distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Given that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Z\sim \operatorname{Unif}(\{\pm1\})$. Prove that $Y = XZ$ is a standard Gaussian distribution.

My approach:
I started trying to find the pdf of them. I found that:
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(z)f_X\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \frac{1}{x} \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(-\frac{(x/y)^2}{2})}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx$$
and I can't seem to find finish the calculation.

So I moved on to the MGF approach with:
$$M_{ZX}(t)=E[e^{zxt}] = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(zxt)\frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{2} \, dx \, dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(\frac{1}{2}(zt)^2) \, dz$$
and again, I can't finish it...
All of the answers seems to lead up to erfi functions...

edit: additional info: $Z$ and $X$ are independent of each other

Comment: In conventional notation $Z\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(\{\pm1\})$ means $\Pr(Z=+1) = \tfrac 1 2 = \Pr(Z=-1).$ So no integral of the form $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{+1}\cdots \, dz$ is involved. $\qquad$

Comment: Duplicate of [Distribution of Product of Random Variables with one being the normal distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325786/distribution-of-product-of-random-variables-with-one-being-the-normal-distributi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the text I understand that Z is a discrete rv taking the values $\pm1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ so,

simply observe that $Y=-X\sim N(0;1)$ (it's trivial but you can derive the result with fundamental transformation theorem)

so $f_Z(z)=1/2\phi(z)+1/2\phi(z)=\phi(z)$