# RVs that are uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, correlation

Given that $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Z\sim Unif(\{\pm 1\})$, and $Y=XZ$. 
$Z$ is independent of $X$. After calculation we found that $Y\sim N(0,1)$.
Show that X and Y are uncorrelated but not independent.

I can only assume that since $Y=XZ$ then, $Y$ must be dependent of $X$.

Comment: I made a mistake of not writing Unif at Z

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064541/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are indepedent then  so are $X^{2}$ and  $Y^{2}$. But $Y^{2}=X^{2}$ since $Z^{2}=1$. This makes $X^{2}$ independent of itself which is possible only when it is a constant. This contradicts the fact that $X \sim N(0,1)$.

By independence $EXY=EX^{2}Z=EX^{2}EZ=(1)(0)=0$ and $EXE(XY)=(0)E(XY)=0$ so cavariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $0$.

Comment: How is $Z^2=1$? Also how do I prove their uncorrelation?

Comment: @SharonZh I have now proved that the covariance is $0$. $Z^{2}=1$ because $(-1)^{2}=1$ and $(1)^{2}=1$. $Z$ takes only the values $\pm 1$.